# Accidentally started deleting python3.5 on ubuntu 16.04 ... how to proceed?

Tags: python, ubuntu, operating-system, ubuntu-16.04

I did something really stupid on my ubuntu 16.04 distribution and would like to ask how I can proceed now.
I looked for a way to uninstall specific python versions and found and executed this:

sudo apt-get remove --purge python3.5

completely forgetting that ubuntu 16.04 is based on this version.
After a few seconds I realized something is wrong since too many things are being deleted and aborted it.
I still have all my files and some software like Mathematica.
Other things, however, are gone ... for example PyCharm, some start menu icons ...
Also, when I open the terminal now, XTerm is being opened.

From what I understand, I really messed up my system and am actually quite lucky to still have all my files (I will save them externally now so any suggestions that include everything being deleted are not problematic as long as everything is normal again afterwards!).

My question is: is there any way to restore everything the way it was before executing the command? If not, can you recommend a way to just switch to ubuntu 18.04 (now that I messed up, I might as well :D).

Sorry for the long story and the number of questions, I'm just trying to be as detailed as possible and very careful with what I do (unlike 10 minutes ago ... :/).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think this will be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/881829/accidentally-deleted-usr-bin-python3-5-cannot-reinstall

Comment: @NikolayPatarov I completely forgot to thank you for your request! It turned out to be trickier than expected but the hint was helpful. Cheers!